# Select Rows in Pandas Based on "OR" over Columns

Tags: pandas

I want to select rows based on whether a certain value occurs at least once in one of a few columns. I could only find examples where one chose rows based on one column containing certain values.

How would I chose `a` and `b` but not `c` because `7` occurred in `[Field1, Field2, Field3]` for `a` and `b` but not `c`.

```
Label Field1 Field2 Field3 ... Other Columns of no Interest
a        7 
b       10      7
c              10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `melt`

```
df.melt('Label').loc[lambda x : x.value==7].Label
Out[14]: 
0    a
4    b
Name: Label, dtype: object
```

Comment: This would give the Label multiple times if 7 appears in multiple columns for the row, which may or may not be OP's desired behaviour.

Comment: Desired behavior = Label appears only once no matter how many times it appears in column.

Comment: @mac389 adding unique `df.melt('Label').loc[lambda x : x.value==7].Label.unique()
`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain all columns of your data, you could instead do:

```
df[df[['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3']].eq(7).any(axis='columns')]
```

Which would give you (depending on where your values are located, it's unclear from the example):

```
    Label   Field1  Field2  Field3
0       a        7     NaN     NaN
1       b       10     7.0     NaN
```